# Is my direct proof correct for $ \prod_{i=2}^{n} \left(1- \frac{1}{i^2}\right) =\frac {n+1}{2n} $ good/correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, products

I need to show via direct proof that:

$$  \prod_{i=2}^{n} \left (1-
\frac{1}{i^2}\right) =\frac {n+1}{2n} $$

We first note that  $$1-\frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i\cdot i}.$$
Then
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=2}^{n}  \left(1-
\frac{1}{i^2}\right)&=\prod_{i=2}^{n} \frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i\cdot i}\\
&=\frac {(n-1)!\cdot \frac{(n+1)!}{2} } {n!\cdot n!}\\
&=\frac {(n-1)!\cdot(n+1)!}{2\cdot n!\cdot n!}\\
&=\frac {(n+1)}{2n}.
\end{align}
Direct proof end.

Is that sufficient enough for a direct proof? Any critique would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Peanut where exactly?

Comment: @saulspatz Do you know what the user Peanut means? I don't see one n more actually?

Comment: @JohnGam it was edited, it's ok now

Answer (score 2):

That’s one way to do it, another way is to note that:

$$\begin{align}1-\frac1{i^2}&=\frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{i-1}{i}}{\frac{i}{i+1}}\\&=\frac{f(i)}{f(i+1)}
\end{align}$$
where $f(k)=\frac{k-1}k.$

So $$\begin{align}\prod_2^n \left(1-\frac1{i^2}\right)&=\frac{f(2)}{f(3)}\frac{f(3)}{f(4)}\cdots \frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)}\\&=\frac{f(2)}{f(n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac12}{\frac{n}{n+1}}\\&=\frac{n+1}{2n}\end{align}$$

(The simplest way to prove this equality is just by induction on $n,$ but your way and mine both show how to find the value, not just prove it is correct.)